# VM host management in case of Linux bridge

Tags: qemu, bridge

I have a virtual-machine host(`vm-host`) which runs two qemu-kvm virtual machines in [tap](http://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#Tap) mode. This means that network topology looks like this:

[image: network setup]

As I need to manage `vm-host` over VLAN 123, I see three approaches:

- I create an `eth0.123` interface in `vm-host` and configure management IP to `eth0.123`
- I create a bridge between `eth0.123` and `br0` and configure management IP to `br0`
- I configure management IP directly to `eth0` in `vm-host` and configure `r1` in a way that it removes VLAN tag 123 for management traffic before it sends it to `vm-host`

Is there a design which is clearly better than the others? I would guess that the third design option is the best one from `vm-host` point of view because server does not need to pop the VLAN tag as it would in case of first two options and management traffic frames do not pass the Linux switch `br0` as it would in case of a second option. In other words, this seems to be the simplest design option. Second option seems to be the worst one because I can't see any advantages of moving that traffic through Linux bridge..

Comment: So what VLAN does the traffic for the virtual machines run in? If it's the same, (and you only get one VLAN to the whole physical box) then you might as well put the vm-host's IP on the bridge interface. If you get multiple VLANs to the box, then should you have separate bridges for each VLAN anyway? (I'm not exactly sure if you can run VLANs over a Linux bridge, but bridges on top of VLANs seems to be more commonly suggested.) How is your bridge constructed currently? (`brctl show`?)

Comment: For virtual machines there are bridges between `eth0.2 <-> tap2` and `eth0.3 <-> tap3` so they run in VLANs `2` and `3` respectively. In other words, as you said, I have a separate bridge for each VLAN. However, as there are more than one way to build the management(I was able to list at least three possibilities my initial post),  I was wondering is there a design which is clearly better(more efficient in terms of server resources, easier to firewall, etc) than the others?

Comment: I asked, because your image only has `br0` with no indication of how the VLANs are separated. Also, there's `tap0` twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your box gets more than one VLAN (on the same interface), I would keep them all tagged. (Instead of e.g. two tagged and one untagged.) That makes the configuration easier to figure out later, since it's explicit what the VLANs in question are. The box has to deal with VLAN tags anyway, and it's not that it would be a bottleneck (compared to parsing IP/TCP/SSH/whatever.)

Also, if you don't really need to bridge the management VLAN to anything, there's no need to put it in a bridge. Not creating a bridge for it makes it clear that the VLAN in question is not meant for your VMs, but for the host itself. (Assuming per-VLAN bridges.)

So, out of those choices, I'd just put the management on eth0.123.

On the other hand, you could dedicate a whole separate NIC for the management. Apart from keeping things clean and separate, it would have the advantage that management traffic and the VMs would not compete for the same bandwidth. Even extreme traffic on the VM networks would not be able to swamp management access directly. (Assuming the box itself and the switch can keep up, of course.)

(I'm not exactly sure if there's any "hard" reason to do one or the other. As you said, there are several ways to do it and it might just be up to personal preference. If in doubt, use the simplest method.)

Answer (score 0):

1. management ip on eth0.123

   Disadvantage - both tagged and untagged traffic flow in bridge, so VMs potentially can forge vlan123. To protect from it You need filter tagged traffic forward in bridge (ebtables tool)

   > ```
   > ebtables -t filter -A FORWARD -p 0x88a8 -j DROP
   > ebtables -t filter -A FORWARD -p 0x8100 -j DROP
   > ```
2. per vlan bridge (as @ilkkachu say) is possible, but it opverkill there and "untaggged" bridge (bound to physical interface directly) suffer from same problem as 1
3. Must be possible set vlan on bridge (br0.123) but it again very similar to 1 and bridge which mix multiple vlans can suffer from nonunique MAC addresses between VLAN.
4. manipuulating VLAN on router to make both vlan untagged, look obfuscated, and not give isolation between host management and gusts in security aspect. But possible, MAC based VLAN on router can be reasonable. If goal to isolate broadcast domains, but not securely isolate host from VMs.

Comment: 1. If I configure management IP to `eth0.123`, then I wouldn't put the `eth0.123` into bridge so IMHO there is no way for VMs to access the management IP.  2. On the other hand, per VLAN bridges should provide best separation between VMs, i.e each VM is in separate broadcast domain. In addition, VMs can have a same MAC address if they are in separate VLANs. 3. I can't see any advantages of configuring management IP on `br0.123`.. To be honest, this looks quite odd design. 4. Only the management traffic would be untagged. VMs traffic would remain tagged.

Comment: 1. in this case. VMs can access management IP, but only over router (possible in host machine itself or external) or external switch. Same as in case 2 (per vlan bridge).